# AttributeError: type object 'StaffFilter' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

When i try to access the urls , it kept return `AttributeError: type object 'StaffFilter' has no attribute '_meta'`. However, i already declared `_meta` in filters.py but the error kept returning. Is there any way to solve this problem ?

`filters.py`

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet
from django_filters import DateTimeFilter, BaseInFilter, CharFilter
from .models import Staff

class StaffFilter(FilterSet):
    department__in = BaseInFilter(field_name="department", lookup_expr='in')
    job_grade__in = BaseInFilter(field_name="job_grade", lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = [
           'job_grade__in',
           'department__in',]
```

Comment: The [DRF integratin docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/main/guide/rest_framework.html#quickstart) show all the imports as coming from `django_filters.rest_framework.*`, whereas you're using `BaseInFilter` etc from the core package - no idea if that would affect things, but a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)` and `filterset_class = StaffFilter` in your API View?

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from myapp import Product


class StaffList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Staff.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = StaffFilter


class StaffFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    department__in = BaseInFilter(field_name="department", lookup_expr='in')
    job_grade__in = BaseInFilter(field_name="job_grade", lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Staff
```

Docs: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class